# What's the format date Node js (new date()) on C#

Tags: c#, node.js, datetime

I get this date from node js :

> //Tue Oct 30 2018 10:06:39 GMT + 0330(Iran Standard Time)

I want to convert this string to DateTime (C#);
this is my code. but I don't know (What's string date format on c#?)

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(json.GetValue("date").ToString(), "ddd MMM dd yyy HH:mm:ss GMT K z", null);
```

Can you help me?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(json.GetValue("date").ToString(), "ddd MMM dd yyy HH:mm:ss ?????????", null);
```

Comment: If you're in control of the date from NodeJs, I'd recommend sending it as an ISO8601 datestring (i.e. `new Date().toISOString();`)

Comment: Thanks. Your comment was helpful.

Comment: :) Glad I could help